# Loading jQuery UI 1.12.x with RequireJS

Tags: jquery-ui, requirejs

I am trying to load jQuery 1.12.1 Slider widget with RequireJS v2.3.5, so I can use a widget called "jquery.selectBoxIt", my setup is like this:

**File structure:**

```
node_modules
AOP/Scripts/app/requireconfig.js
```

**requireconfig.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/AOP/Scripts',
    paths: {
        'jquery.selectboxit': '../../node_modules/selectboxit/src/javascripts/jquery.selectBoxIt'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.selectboxit': ['jquery.ui.slider']
    },
    packages: [{
        name: 'jquery.ui.slider',
        location: '../../node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets',
        main: 'slider'
    }],
});
```

but I am getting these errors:

```
http://dev.k2.aop.local/AOP/Scripts/keycode.js 
Uncaught Error: Script error for "keycode", needed by: jquery.ui.slider/slider

GET http://dev.k2.aop.local/AOP/Scripts/widget.js 
Uncaught Error: Script error for "widget", needed by: jquery.ui.slider/slider

Uncaught Error: Script error for "version", needed by: jquery.ui.slider/slider
http://dev.k2.aop.local/AOP/Scripts/version.js 

Uncaught Error: Script error for "ie", needed by: jquery.ui.slider/mouse
http://dev.k2.aop.local/AOP/Scripts/ie.js

Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: jquery.selectboxit
```

I had tried to add all these dependencies as RequireJs packages but at the end this error pops out again

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: jquery.selectboxit,keycode/version,widget/version,ie/version
```

Comment: So the only error remaining is the last one? Did you check your network tab in the debugging console? Is RequireJS fetching the right file? Is the file getting downloaded or is it failing with an error (like 404)?

Comment: @Louis In devtools source panel all files are loader but error is a little bit different 'Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: jquery.selectboxit,keycode/version,widget/version,ie/version'